# Can we make use of AWS S3 connectivity with HPCC Cluster without administrative access to the cluster?

Tags: amazon-s3, hpcc-ecl, hpcc

So I wanted to look on how one can develop AWS S3 connectivity with a HPCC Cluster. Tools like s3cmd and aws cli work well if I am accessing files from my S3 bucket onto my localhost cluster by getting into the directory of the landing zone, which is on my local machine in this case. However, is there a way to extract files from the S3 bucket without any administrative access, just by using ECL IDE (probably on another non-local cluster)?

There is no specific plugin for AWS S3 connectivity with HPCC Cluster, so I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you want to do, you should look at the PIPE() function.

Comment: I wanted to find a way for transferring files from S3 to the landing zone of the cluster. The PIPE() function was useful since I was able to run dfuplus commands. If I make use of the approach of s3cmd and aws cli, I would need access to the landing zone to configure them, which I probably might not have.